# Как для селекта сделать массив, чтобы с массива передать в селект варианты выбора

Tags: php

Подскажите как для селекта сделать массив, и потом в селекте из массива подгружать варианты для выбора.

Вариант как сделать селект есть.

```
<select name="celect1" id="celect1">
<?php foreach($options as $opt) : ?>
<option value="<?php echo $opt->name?>"><?php echo $opt->name?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Как теперь сделать массив? чтоб от туда данные в селект выводить.

Comment: [(object)['name'=>'a'], (object)['name'=>'b']] и так далее

Comment: Не совсем понял, мне бы весь пример целого массива, не делал такое, по этому кусок кода не пойму.

Comment: это и есть целый массив

Comment: а как задействовать его, чет не пойму.

Comment: так как у вас в коде уже написано

Comment: Он же так ищет переменную с которой надо подгружать варианты, вывод информации  с переменной он написан, это я понял, а как теперь переменную создать где будут вписаны эти варианты для вывода. так? <?php $options [(options)['name'=>'a'], (options)['name'=>'b']] ?>

Comment: не знаю. как вам объяснить, написал код в ответе

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение, где я еще вывожу цену с массива в один из вариантов оптионса.

```
<?php
$dataprice= $user->price();
$options= [
(object)['name' => 'вариант1', 'dataprice' => '', 'name2' => 'вариант1'],
(object)['name' => 'вариант2', 'dataprice' => $dataprice, 'name2' => "вариант2 (+ вывести $dataprice руб, к сумме)"],
(object)['name' => 'вариант3', 'dataprice' =>'', 'name2' => 'вариант3'],
];
?>

<select name="celect1" id="celect1">
<?php foreach($options as $opt) : ?>
<option value="<?php echo $opt->name?>" data-price="<?php echo $opt->dataprice?>"><?php echo $opt->name?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $options = [(object)['name'=>'a'], (object)['name'=>'b']]; 
?>
<select name="celect1" id="celect1">
<?php foreach($options as $opt) : ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $opt->name?>"><?php echo $opt->name?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: как все просто ), вот теперь понятно, я чуть не так пытался сделать )

Comment: а как добавить в вариантам, допустим нумерацию валует?  попробовал так, для первого варианта валуе 0 поставить, (object)['name' => 'Выберите', 'value' => '0'], так ошибка

Comment: какая ошибка? `value="<?php echo $opt->value?>`

Comment: да так и вписал value="<?php echo $opt->value?>, ошибка ErrorException [ Notice ]: Undefined property: stdClass::$value

Comment: только в одном объекте вписали? тогда надо уж во всех

Comment: а во все, я только для одного хотел, 0 вывести, а для всех остальных name как быть.

Comment: нашел решение, там просто был как бы пустой пункт, заглушка, <option value="0">Выберите</option>, я его в массив не стал пихать, а просто поверх запихал и все.